# How can I simply check various variables for one statement?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement

I want to check about 7 variables for the same statement, but it is not required. All that variables have an array with custom keys.

I have, for example, this code:

```
$generalSettings = array(
"lights" = $_POST['generalLights'],
"tones" = $_POST['generalTones']
);
```

(And several more.)

Now, I want to check if the value is 1; if not, the value has to be set to 0.

I would do it like this:

```
if($generalSettings['ligts'] == 1) {
$generalSettings['lights'] = 1;
} else {
$generalSettings['lights'] = 0;
}
if($generalSettings['tones'] = 1) {
$generalSettings['tones'] = 1;
} else {
$generalSettings['tones'] = 0;
}
```

This is a lot of work, if you think of 3 arrays with 4 items and four arrays with five items.

My question now is: Can I do this in a simpler way, and if yes, how?

Comment: (foreach elements as element) { check(element) }

Answer (score 0):

You can check like below

```
$arr = array('a'=>1,'b'=>4,'c'=>9,'d'=>1);
```

loop through array and check values if value is not 1 then set 0

```
foreach($arr  as $key=>$value){
     if($value != 1){
         $arr[$key] = 0;
     }
 }

 echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);

Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 0
    [c] => 0
    [d] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you. What can I do for several arrays? Can I put this foreach in another one? I  yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop for:

```
foreach ($generalSettings as $key) {
  if($generalSettings[$key] == 1)
    $generalSettings[$key] = 1;
  else
    $generalSettings[$key] = 0;
}
```

Comment: is the variable $key a keyword or should I define it? If I have to define it: how should I do so?
looks simple, thanks!

Comment: it is a variable created by `foreach` loop that holds the iterator element. No need to define/declare it.